# How to write test cases for drawing text / string in a box?

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, ocunit

I am drawing strings in a rectangular frame. The string is drawing perfectly. Now I need to write test cases using sentesting kit. I have no ideas from where I should start. For help I have also seen the [iPhone sample calculator application](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/samplecode/iPhoneUnitTests/Introduction/Intro.html)

But still out of sorts.

Any body having ideas please help.

Thanks,

Madhup

Comment: Please stop creating redundant tags. OCUnit *is* SenTestingKit. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ocunit.

Answer (score 1):

GUI drawing code is often hard to test. In your case it depends how you draw your string. If you draw it into a custom view by using the `-(void)drawRect:` method and therein just drawing your NSString (I suppose), then I do not think your can test that this drawing happend properly.
If you use a separate view like a `UITextLabel` you could test for its existance by using `STAssertNotNil`. You could also check the proper positioning by checking the view's bounds.

If you need more help, please be a bit more specific and adding clean code would help.